# formset delete inline instance

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Have identified the object that i need to delete from the formset.

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            ......
        if formset.deleted_forms:
            for obj in formset.deleted_forms:
               obj.delete() //here is the issue
```

it ends with the error

```
*** AttributeError: 'ActivitiesForm' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

This is what formset.deleted_forms is

```
(Pdb) formset.deleted_forms
[<django.forms.widgets.ActivitiesForm object at 0x7f19f6435f50>]
```

What went wrong here? Basically i m trying to delete inline entry choosen from admin

Comment: Obviously there is no `delete` method for that object, but I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: assume that you have uploaded a inline table content. and you want to delete it!! when we override save_formset(). How do we handle it?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a model formset, you should loop through `deleted_objects`, not `deleted_forms`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset) for more info.

```
for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
    obj.delete()
```

Note that before Django 1.7 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#miscellaneous)), you didn't need to manually delete the objects. The objects were deleted when you called save(), even with `commit=False`.

Comment: formset.deleted_objects doesn't exit                             <django.forms.formsets.ActivitiesFormFormSet object at 0x7f19dc35f2d0>
(Pdb) formset.deleted_forms
[<django.forms.widgets.ActivitiesForm object at 0x7f19dc35f0d0>]
(Pdb) formset.deleted_objects
*** AttributeError: 'ActivitiesFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'deleted_objects'

Comment: It looks like you might be using an old version of Django.

Comment: django 1.7 is what i m using

Comment: In that case, I don't know why you are getting the `AttributeError`. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: If you aren't in the admin you won't have that `deleted_objects` attribute. You will need to use `deleted_forms`

Comment: @surfer190 that's incorrect. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete) show that `deleted_objects` is a feature of `ModelFormSet`, they are not tied to the admin.

Comment: ipdb> from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet
ipdb> issubclass(project_memberships.__class__, BaseModelFormSet)
True
ipdb> project_memberships.deleted_objects
*** AttributeError: 'ProjectMembershipFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'deleted_objects'

Comment: @surfer190 this is off topic for the original question, you would be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

For `ModelForms` you can delete the instance object tied to the form:

```py
for form in formset.deleted_forms:
    if form.instance.pk:
        form.instance.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

in Django >=1.11 you can override deletion on formset:

```
class YourInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        if commit:
            do_delete_it_your_way()
```